# Does the knife master ability stack with prestige classes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, rogue

I'm making a villain for a campaign, and he's going to be an assassin/rogue combo. I wanted him to have a bit more bite, though, so I decided to make him a knife master.

**Would the sneak stab ability that the [knife master rogue archetype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/archetypes/paizo---rogue-archetypes/knife-master) gives change the sneak attack damage from the levels of assassin as well, or would that damage remain d6s while the rogue-levels sneak attack deals d8s/d4s?**

EDIT: Sneak Stab wording;

> A knife master focuses her ability to deal sneak attack damage with daggers and similar weapons to such a degree that she can deal more sneak attack damage with those weapons at the expense of sneak attacks with other weapons. When she makes a sneak attack with a dagger, kerambit, kukri, punching daggers, starknife, or swordbreaker dagger, she uses d8s to roll sneak attack damage instead of d6s. For sneak attacks with all other weapons, she uses d4s instead of d6s. 
>   This ability is identical in all other ways to sneak attack, and supplements that ability.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does say “when she uses Sneak Attack” and that this ability “supplements” that ability. I would argue that it applies to all abilities named Sneak Attack – the Knife Master doesn’t really gain a different form of precision damage that’s similar-to-but-distinct-from Sneak Attack, she gains an ability that modifies Sneak Attack. It would apply to all Sneak Attack that she has.

Certainly, from a balance/ease-of-play/flavor sense, it should apply.